# How to surface errors from AWS Step Functions distributed map subworkflows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

In the distributed map flow for Step Functions, is there a way to surface errors from the child workflows to the main step function execution?

It seems that in the main execution, any error from the child executions is overwritten by the States.ExceedToleratedFailureThreshold error.

My SFN executions only show ExceedToleratedFailureThreshold, no matter what error is thrown from the child workflows.
This was not an issue when not using Distributed mode.

```
Task1Map:
  Type: Map
  MaxConcurrency: 50
  ResultPath: null
  Next: Task1TypeChoice
  ItemReader:
    ReaderConfig:
      InputType: JSON
    Resource: arn:aws:states:::s3:getObject
    Parameters:
      Bucket.$: $.map_parameters_bucket
      Key.$: $.map_parameters_key
  ItemProcessor:
    ProcessorConfig:
      Mode: DISTRIBUTED
      ExecutionType: STANDARD
    StartAt: someTask
    States:
      someTask:
        Type: Task
        Resource: arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync
        ResultPath: null
        Parameters:
          JobDefinition.$: $.some_task_job_definition
(...)
  Catch:
    - ErrorEquals: ["States.ALL"]
      ResultPath: $.error
```

Comment: add complete template of .asl @yd0531

Comment: @saurabhkamble added more details, I use serverless framework.